# How to add groups of files?

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit

I am trying to add the shareKit files like in the photo:

[image]

...but Xcode will only let me do the drag and drop only for single files! How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you not create a static library out of this `ShareKit` files/folders and then just add it as if it was a framework.

Comment: but this is not only for ShareKit, its for every project I want to import so I need to fix it

Comment: You turn it into a static library you can update one code for all projects that have the static library import (import into many projects not just one). Quite hard to get working but when its done it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is simple:

1) Right click the sharekit folder in the first project and you will see show in finder. Click that.

2) That will lead to the folder in your directory.

3) Next pull the whole directory into second project. Make sure you copy the files over.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried that but the folders are blue not yellow, and if you call the files they won't be recognised. you would need to drag all the files in but there are more than 20 folders other folders in that one

Comment: Remove the folder that you just added.. And redo what i told to do again but this time, when you add the folder and it says copy over, there is a option below that says create groups for any added folders.. click that instead of the other... hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4 it is different than older Xcode you have in the screenshot. To copy between projects, you have to open them in the same workspace (the same window). So

1. open the first project
2. drag the second one from finder to the same Xcode workspace
3. now drag the files you need
4. remove the second project from your workspace.

Lakesh's approach might have a risk in fact, that sometimes file structure you see in xcode might differ from what is actually on filesystem.

You might want to try [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/sharekit/sharekit), it is already packaged as a static lib and has updated sharers to match newest api's. If you decide to use it, make sure to follow [install wiki guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) literally.

---